# Proof that $ f(x)=\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x} $ where $a>0,b>0,a\neq b$ monotonously increases

Tags: functions

Known $$ f(x)=\left(\frac{a^x+b^x}{2}\right)^{1/x} $$
where $a>0, b>0,a\neq b$. Proof $f(x)$ monotonously increases ($x\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$)?

Start with the most common way, its derivative is,
$$ f'(x)={(a^x + b^x)^{-1 + 1/x} (a^x x \ln a + b^x x \ln b + (a^x + b^x) (\ln 2 - \ln(a^x + b^x))) \over 2^{1/x} x^2} $$

Any ideas for solving this? Or is there a better way to solve?

Answer (score 1):

If $\mu(dy)$ is a probability on $R$ such that $e^{k(x)}=\int_Re^{xy}\mu(dx)<\infty$ for all $x>0$ then $x\mapsto k(x)$ is convex on $[0,\infty)$ by Holder inequality and $k(0)=1$ since $\mu$ is a probability. Therefore
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{k(x)}{x}=\frac{xk'(x)-k(x)}{x^2}>0$$ since $k_1(x)=xk'(x)-k(x)$ satisfies $k_1(0)=0$ and $k_1'(x)=xk''(x)>0.$ Application $$\mu(dy)=\frac{1}{2}(\delta_{\log a}(dy)+\delta_{\log b}(dy)).$$